# How can I locate an element by header or any particular property value in Protractor?

Tags: protractor

I have an element that have no Id defined. Class name do not allow me to identify the element uniquely. 
That's why I would like to locate it using `role` or `header` property:

```
<p-dialog header="Deleting" showeffect="fade" role="dialog"
class="ng-tns"> </p-dialog>
```

How should I do that in Protractor / Selenium Webdriver?
I can do that by means of xpath, but as I understand it's rather suggested to [avoid it at all](https://www.protractortest.org/#/style-guide#never-use-xpath).
Do I need to define my own locator using [addLocator](https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorBy.prototype.addLocator) or is there simpler solution?

Answer (score 1):

Protractor recommend to use css selector as first option, xpath as the secondary option when css selector can resolve your problem in some cases.

The primary reason of such recommendation considered followings:

1. xpath is not fast than css selector
2. xpath is case sensitive in some browser
3. for lower IE, like 6 not support xpath natively
4. xpath generally is longer than css selector to find same element

But css selector has two shortage which xpath is able to do:

1. can't find element by text
2. can't find parent element (only can find downward)

For your case, you can try following locator:

```
// css selector
p-dialog[header="Deleting"]
p-dialog[role="dialog"]
p-dialog[header="Deleting"][role="dialog"]
```

Comment: Thank you. What resources do you suggest to learn how to construct complex css and xpath locators for particular elements on page?

Comment: @matandked, For basic syntax of css select and xpath,  so many resource can be fount. To become master,  practice is the best way.